# Get noticed when an application tries to take a screenshot (windows)

Tags: windows, screenshot

I need my application to get noticed when another process is trying to do any screen capture.  Is that doable ?

Comment: What do you mean by noticed?  You might be able to set a Windows hook and watch for WM_PRINT...

Comment: FWIW, this question is not the same but similar enough to possibly be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455623/how-can-i-prevent-users-from-taking-screenshots-of-my-application-window.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, btw if I intercept the WM_PRINT message, is it possible to determine if it's the full screen being captured or a single window ?

Answer (score 1):

do a windows hook and watch for WM_PRINT

Answer (score -2):

You can use RegisterHotKey API to get intercept print screen key presses. Another approach would be to use low level keyboard hooks. Few examples:
http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/133059.html 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc301431(en-us).aspx 
[How do i capture the Print Screen key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191479/how-do-i-capture-the-print-screen-key)

Comment: You are making the assumption that the only way to capture the screen is with the "Print Screen" key. OneNote uses Windows+S to initiate a screen capture. FastStone Capture allows users to change the screen capture hot keys, and so on.

Comment: Oops!! I missed that custom keys can be defined for screen capture!! Thanks for pointing it out.