# Form_Keydown event is not working when PrintScreen is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown, printscreen

I'm trying to detect the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key on my form, but keys like <kbd>Prtsc</kbd> and <kbd>SysRq</kbd> don't fire the `KeyDown` event..

```
    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Trying to detect if it fires KeyDown, but it doesn't
        MessageBox.Show(e.KeyValue.ToString());
    }
```

I can't figure it out, maybe I'm really dumb..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i capture the Print Screen key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191479/how-do-i-capture-the-print-screen-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, but it's not straightforward.  You can't do it with the `KeyPress` or `KeyDown` events:  as you have discovered, it doesn't make them fire.

But you can still do it with c#:  you just have to use the Windows APIs.  Because the relevant code is lengthy, I'm posting the link:

[Capturing the Print Screen Key](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94b1598f-79ce-4c70-8851-86aff6d9b12f/capturing-the-print-screen-key?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Incidentally, you're not dumb.  :)  Even though this seems like it should have an obvious, simple answer, it doesn't:  this is genuinely complex to make happen.  But it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The Key handling events will work only **when a key is pressed while the form has focus.**
The Form properties events and methods are described in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_forms.htm. the following code will display the pressed key name(vb.net) in message box

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        MsgBox(e.KeyCode.ToString)
End Sub
```

You can trace out the Print screen key's press by using the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.PrintScreen Then
        MsgBox("Print screen key is pressed")
    End If
End Sub
```

Note :- **This will not work in laptops in which the `PrintScreen` is achieved through function key.**
**For key code reference:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa243025(v=vs.60).aspx

- **I think their is no problem with your code the reason is that your form doesn't have focus while the key is pressed.**
- **The tab index `0`is assigned to any other control in the form so the initial focus will set to that control**

Sorry am not so good in C#, you can refer http://converter.telerik.com/ for code conversion

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is creating a `HotKey Control`, so there is focus on the form.

Comment: @ joery : It is clearly mentioned that the keyDown event will work only when the form having focus. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_forms.htm (form events. 10)