# c# prevent screen capture of UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

The execs at my company would like a particular custom control of our ui to make a best-effort at preventing screen capture.  I implemented a slick solution using [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [DWMEnableComposition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at the top Window level of our application to prevent screen capture of the entire app but the previously mentioned execs weren't happy with that.  They want only the particular UserControl to prevent screen capture, not the entire app.

The custom control is a .NET 2.0 Windows.Forms.UserControl wrapped in a 4.5 WPF WindowsFormsHost contained by a 4.5 WPF Window control.

Before I tell the execs where to go, I want to be certain there isn't a reasonable way to implement this.

So, my question is: How do I implement screen capture prevention of a .NET 2.0 UserControl?

Thanks

Comment: I don't actually think you can do that...

Comment: Side note: I'd strongly recommend to cleanup your personal opinions about your employer from your post - not nice and completely unnecessary on SO.

Comment: Who are they fooling? If your app is displayed on a screen, It will be possible for someone to capture it. Period. The security solution must be something else then preventing a capture.

Comment: your best effort was not best enough!!!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov There are no personal opinions about my employer in this post.  Please keep your personal opinions unrelated to answering the question off my post and off SO.

Comment: Even if you could prevent anything running on that machine from doing a capture, what would prevent someone from taking a picture of the screen with their cell phone?

Comment: @CoderDennis The app is installed with a [cartoon-goon](http://popeye.wikia.com/wiki/Alice_the_Goon) that stands behind the user to prevent fotos of the screen. Read the post: BEST EFFORT!!!  And I argue that even fotos could be prevented using various forms of visual crypto, but that would take a bit more work than best-effort.  BTW: You can prevent on-machine screen capture of an app using SetWindowDisplayAffinity API call.

Comment: That's not going to prevent everything, and you're certainly not going to stop people from taking a picture with their cell phone.

Comment: @mason did you even read the post? or any of the comments?

Comment: @Mindy Sure did. You're fighting a losing battle, "best effort" won't count. If the data is sent to the user, the user can and **will** find a way to utilize that data. You want to prevent people from stealing data? Disconnect the machine from the Internet, put the computer in an access controlled and monitored room, strip and cavity search them when they enter and leave. That won't prevent people with photographic memories of course, but that's the only realistic option for effectively preventing someone from taking data you gave them access to.

Comment: If your executives don't understand this, then I would question their competence as executives in a company that wants to keep secrets in the year 2015. It's incredibly important for executives in that line of business to have a thorough knowledge of security limitations. You can suggest they attend some executive focused security conferences.

Comment: I'm really sorry for reading your post wrong. I perfectly understand that "[tell ... where to go"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tell%20him%20where%20to%20go) represent very level headed and professional expression of disagreement with someones opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

i had an idea:
the user click "PrintScreen", a capture from my program is copy to **ClipBoard**.
So, all what i need it: to catch cliboard an check if he contains an image.
if yes: i delete the image from clipboard.

the code:

```
//definition a timer
public static Timer getImageTimer = new Timer();
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    getImageTimer.Interval = 500;
    getImageTimer.Tick += GetImageTimer_Tick;
    getImageTimer.Start();

    ......

}

private static void GetImageTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())//if clipboard contains an image
                Clipboard.Clear();//delete
        }
```

*but it avoid any time program is running. (you need to know if your program is foreground, and then check clipboard);

Answer (score 0):

You **might** be able to capture the key stroke.

Below is a method I used for that, but it had limited success:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
  if ((m_parent != null) && m_parent.ScreenCapture(ref msg)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
  }
}

protected override bool ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref Message msg) {
  if ((m_parent != null) && m_parent.ScreenCapture(ref msg)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return base.ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref msg);
  }
}
```

Returning "True" was supposed to tell the system that the PrintScreen routine was handled, but it often still found the data on the clipboard.

What I did instead, as you can see from the call to `m_parent.ScreenCapture`, was to save the capture to a file, then display it in my own custom image viewer.

If it helps, here is the wrapper I created for the custom image viewer in `m_parent.ScreenCapture`:

```
public bool ScreenCapture(ref Message msg) {
  var WParam = (Keys)msg.WParam;
  if ((WParam == Keys.PrintScreen) || (WParam == (Keys.PrintScreen & Keys.Alt))) {
    ScreenCapture(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
    msg = new Message(); // erases the data
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

public void ScreenCapture(string initialDirectory) {
  this.Refresh();
  var rect = new Rectangle(Location.X, Location.Y, Size.Width, Size.Height);
  var imgFile = Global.ScreenCapture(rect);
  //string fullName = null;
  string filename = null;
  string extension = null;
  if ((imgFile != null) && imgFile.Exists) {
    filename = Global.GetFilenameWithoutExt(imgFile.FullName);
    extension = Path.GetExtension(imgFile.FullName);
  } else {
    using (var worker = new BackgroundWorker()) {
      worker.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        Thread.Sleep(300);
        var bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
          g.CopyFromScreen(Location, Point.Empty, rect.Size); // WinForm Only
        }
        e.Result = bmp;
      };
      worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Error != null) {
          var err = e.Error;
          while (err.InnerException != null) {
            err = err.InnerException;
          }
          MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Screen Capture", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        } else if (e.Cancelled) {
        } else if (e.Result != null) {
          if (e.Result is Bitmap) {
            var bitmap = (Bitmap)e.Result;
            imgFile = new FileInfo(Global.GetUniqueFilenameWithPath(m_screenShotPath, "Screenshot", ".jpg"));
            filename = Global.GetFilenameWithoutExt(imgFile.FullName);
            extension = Path.GetExtension(imgFile.FullName);
            bitmap.Save(imgFile.FullName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
          }
        }
      };
      worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
  }
  if ((imgFile != null) && imgFile.Exists && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(extension)) {
    bool ok = false;
    using (SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog()) {
      dlg.Title = "ACP Image Capture: Image Name, File Format, and Destination";
      dlg.FileName = filename;
      dlg.InitialDirectory = m_screenShotPath;
      dlg.DefaultExt = extension;
      dlg.AddExtension = true;
      dlg.Filter = "PNG Image|*.png|Jpeg Image (JPG)|*.jpg|GIF Image (GIF)|*.gif|Bitmap (BMP)|*.bmp" +
        "|EWM Image|*.emf|TIFF Image|*.tif|Windows Metafile (WMF)|*.wmf|Exchangable image file|*.exif";
      dlg.FilterIndex = 0;
      if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
        imgFile = imgFile.CopyTo(dlg.FileName, true);
        m_screenShotPath = imgFile.DirectoryName;
        ImageFormat fmtStyle;
        switch (dlg.FilterIndex) {
          case 2: fmtStyle = ImageFormat.Jpeg; break;
          case 3: fmtStyle = ImageFormat.Gif; break;
          case 4: fmtStyle = ImageFormat.Bmp; break;
          case 5: fmtStyle = ImageFormat.Emf; break;
          case 6: fmtStyle = ImageFormat.Tiff; break;
          case 7: fmtStyle = ImageFormat.Wmf; break;
          case 8: fmtStyle = ImageFormat.Exif; break;
          default: fmtStyle = ImageFormat.Png; break;
        }
        ok = true;
      }
    }
    if (ok) {
      string command = string.Format(@"{0}", imgFile.FullName);
      try { // try default image viewer
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(command);
        Process.Start(psi);
      } catch (Exception) {
        try { // try IE
          ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("iexplore.exe", command);
          Process.Start(psi);
        } catch (Exception) { }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote that years ago, and I don't work there now. The source code is still in my Cloud drive so that I can leverage skills I learned once (and forgot).

That code isn't meant to get you completely done, but just to show you a way of doing it. If you need any help with something, let me know.

Comment: In hindsight, I suppose I could have physically deleted the contents of the clipboard ...or replaced it with something mischievous. :)

Comment: thanks for the response, but not quite what i'm after.  i'm looking for a solution to handle screen capture more generally (snipping tools, etc), not just print screen.  SetWindowDisplayAffinity would be perfect except it only works on top level windows.

Comment: I would think the solution you are describing would involve finding a way to physically control the graphics, because most apps like Greenshot and Microsoft's Clip tool are getting their info from the graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

Not a silver bullet, but could form part of a strategy...
If you were worried about the windows snipping tool or other known snipping tools, you could subscribe to Windows events to capture a notification of when SnippingTool.exe was launched and then hide your application until it was closed:

```
        var applicationStartWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
        applicationStartWatcher.EventArrived += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString().StartsWith("SnippingTool"))
                {
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden);
                }
            };
        applicationStartWatcher.Start();

        var applicationCloseWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));
        applicationCloseWatcher.EventArrived += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString().StartsWith("SnippingTool"))
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        this.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        this.Activate();
                    });
            }
        };
        applicationCloseWatcher.Start();
```

You will probably need to be running as an administrator for this code to work.
ManagementEventWatcher is in the System.Management assembly.

This coupled with some strategy for handling the print screen key: for example something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191479/how-do-i-capture-the-print-screen-key) may at least make it difficult to screen capture.