# Can I listen for the PRINT SCREEN event?

Tags: c#, windows, printscreen

Most examples on here are people creating a screen shot manually in C#.

My goal is to listen for the PRINTSCREEN keyboard event, and after the event is called I take the clipboard data and do something with it. I need to make sure I only access the clipboard after the PRINTSCREEN event has captured the screenshot.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Q: Can I capture a "print screen" event in C#?  A: Yes: [How do i capture the Print Screen key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191479/how-do-i-capture-the-print-screen-key)

Comment: I am not sure the other answered question fulfill the whole question here. "I need to make sure I only access the clipboard *after* the PRINTSCREEN event has *captured the screenshot*."

Answer (score 1):

1. Press the print screen key.
2. Check which type of clipboard data it is by using code.
3. With this info, code something that cleans or knows what is the last value of this clipboard data type.
4. When print screen is pressed, look in clipboard until this data type is changed and then take it.